# Data Annotations for Display Name are not rendering in Razor form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, data-annotations

I'm trying to assign a display name in my model class using data annotations, but the view is not displaying the name.  It's defaulting to the property name and ignoring the data annotation.

In my model:

```
public interface IFeedbackLogMetadata
{
        [Display(Name="Description")]
        string FeedbackDescription { get; set; }
}
public partial class FeedbackLog : PersistantEntity, IFeedbackLogMetadata
{
//..other stuff
}
```

I have also tried:

```
[DisplayName("Description")]
string FeedbackDescription { get; set; }
```

In my view, I have tried:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.FeedbackDescription, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
<label class="control-label col-md-2">@Html.DisplayNameFor(d => d.FeedbackDescription)</label>
```

The label displays "FeedbackDescription".  It should be "Description".  Why is the display name data annotation being ignored?

Comment: Make sure you don't have a `Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates` for string that is overriding it.

Comment: @SteveGreene - I don't.

Answer (score 0):

/*Headsmack*/

I needed to decorate the partial class with the MetadataType for the interface.  Without this, the view is pulling from the EF generated class, which doesn't have the data annotations.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(IFeedbackLogMetadata))]
public partial class FeedbackLog : PersistantEntity, IFeedbackLogMetadata
{
//...other stuff
}
```